# Unitary change of X basis, shankar, quantum mechanics 7.4.9

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I'm currently working through Shankar's Quantum Mechanics and am stuck on one of his exercises.

In Exercise 7.4.9 Shankar would like us to show

$$|\tilde{x}\rangle = \exp(ig(x)/\hbar) |x\rangle$$ where 
$$g(x) = \int f(x')dx'$$

then,

$$\langle \tilde{x}|P| \tilde{x}' \rangle  = \left(-i \hbar \frac{d}{dx} +f(x)\right)\delta(x-x').$$
I don't get how $f(x)$ is generated there.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it boils down to $g(x)$ being defined as antiderivative of $f(x)$, or $f(x)$ being defined as derivative of $g(x)$, respectively.

Then you only need to keep track of the phase factors, product rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus. The latter should take care of your question regarding $f(x)$.